# error: The argument type 'double?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, textfield

I'm Trying to convert a unit value from one to another. (Kilogram --> Gram) as. I'm getting the following error while converting the value.

I have a map in a different page. as follows

```
final Map<String,double> changes= {
    "gram-kilogram": 0.01,
    "kilogram-gram": 1000,
    "kilogram-kilogram": 1,
    "gram-gram": 1,
  };
```

And the code in the main page containers,

```
  String _val1 = "Kilogram";
  String _val2 = "Kilogram";
  TextEditingController _controller1 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _controller2 = TextEditingController();

  initState(){
    super.initState();
    _controller1=TextEditingController();
    _controller2=TextEditingController();
  }
  dispose(){
    super.dispose();
    _controller1.dispose();
    _controller2.dispose();
  }
```

And There are 2 text fields and 2 drop down buttons.

```
TextField(
                  controller: _controller1,
                  onChanged: (text) {
                    if(text.isEmpty)
                      _controller2.text = "0.0";
                    else
                     _controller2.text = (double.parse(text)*changes[_val1+"-"+_val2]).toString();
                      },
                  ),

DropdownButton<String>(
                  items: <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[
                    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Kilogram"), value: "Kilogram", onTap: () {
                      _val1 = _val1;

                    },),
                    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Gram"),
                      value: "Gram",
                      onTap: () {
                        _val1 = _val1;
                      },),
                  ],
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(()  {
                      this._val1 = value!;
                    });
                  },
                  value: _val1,
                ),
```

I'm getting the error mentioned in the topic. It's occurring in this line. `_controller2.text = (double.parse(text)changes[_val1+"-"+_val2]).toString();` and help would be appreciated.

[image: Screen image]

Comment: Can you mention by using "_controller2.text = (double.parse(text)changes[_val1+"-"+_val2]).toString();" what do you want as a desired result...??

Comment: @LaKiThakare So let's say the user selects Kilogram on the left menubutton and Gram on the right menubutton. Then When the user types 1 in the left Text Field, I want the right Text Field to automatically change to 1000.

Comment: Okay got your problem..... Instead of parse try using tryparse... i.e. double.tryParse(text) * .... Etc.

Comment: @LaKiThakare Then I'll get the same error and error: The operator '*' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. This error too. I added the entire code, if it helps - https://codeshare.io/vwAzZk

Comment: Okay got your problem..... Instead of parse try using tryParse and take care of null safety... i.e. double.tryParse(text) ??  0.0 * .... Etc. This should work.. forgot to mention the null safety one...

Comment: @LaKiThakare Still get the error: The argument type 'double?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235354/discussion-between-lakshan-costa-and-laki-thakare).

Answer (score 0):

You have declare wrong value to Map

```
 Map<String, double> changes= new HashMap<>();

 changes.put("gram-kilogram", 0.01);
 changes.put("kilogram-gram", 1000);
 changes.put("kilogram-kilogram", 1);
 changes.put("gram-gram", 1);
```